# For certain commutative squares involving product projections: when are they pushouts?

Tags: category-theory

In a category with finite products the following diagram commutes for every $f:a\rightarrow b$.
$\require{AMScd}$

\begin{CD}
a \times b @>{\pi_1}>> b \\
@V{id\times f}VV @VV{f}V \\
a\times c @>{\pi_1}>> c
\end{CD}

(If $a$ is terminal then the square is trivially a pushout.
In the category of sets and functions, if $a$ is empty then the square is a pushout if and only if $f$ is an iso.)

Question: assuming that the square is a pushout, can we deduce anything about $a$ or $f$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In $\mathsf{Set}$, this square is a pushout if and only if:

- $a$ is empty and $f$ is a bijection,
- $a$ is a singleton, or
- $|a|>1$ and $f$ is surjective.

This condition is sufficiently complicated that I very much doubt you'll be able to find a satisfying generalization to an arbitrary category with finite products.

---

**Edit:** Now let's consider your question in the category $\mathsf{Set}^{\text{op}}$. This is equivalent to the question of when the following square is a pullback in $\mathsf{Set}$:
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
c @>{i_2}>> a\sqcup c \\
@V{f}VV @VV{\text{id}\sqcup f}V \\
b @>{i_2}>> a\sqcup b
\end{CD}
The answer is: Always!

While you can certainly find sufficient general conditions for your square to be a pushout in a category with finite products (certainly whenever $a$ is terminal or $f$ is an iso, the square is a pushout), but the example of $\mathsf{Set}^{\text{op}}$ convinces me that there will be no nontrivial necessary condition in general. That is, assuming the square is a pushout gives no further information about $f$ or $a$ in general.

Comment: I appreciate the characterization in Set, but I don't know if the conclusion is valid. If the category has an initial object $i$ such that $i\times b = i$ for every $b$ then one can prove that the square is a pushout iff $f$ is an iso. The case of $a$ terminal is already in the statement. In an arbitrary category not every object is a copower of $1$ but what if $a$ contains $1 + 1$ as a subobject? What if the category is regular and/or cartesian closed? I know it would help to have an explicit conjecture but I don't have one.

Comment: @Boogie I've updated my answer.

Comment: I understood the question to be about the context of categories with finite products. I don't doubt that if you assume more about the category, then you can come up with further piecemeal conditions. But note that the condition you suggest ($0\times b\cong 0$ for all $b$, where $0$ is initial) is in some sense a very unusual condition for a category with finite products to satisfy: it says the initial object $0$ is [strict](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3510344/7062). My intuition is that even for toposes there won't be a satisfying general characterization of when the square is a pushout.

Comment: The opposite of $\mathbf{Set}$ is an interesting example. Indeed it shows that little can be said in the context of arbitrary categories with finite products. So I'll considered the question answered. Nevertheless, I still feel there should be useful results. For instance, I don't know if the opposite of sets is cartesian closed.

Comment: $\textbf{Set}^\textrm{op}$ is not cartesian closed. In a cartesian closed category, initial objects are strict; this is not so in $\textbf{Set}^\textrm{op}$.

Comment: Zhen Lin, thanks for the observation. Can you say anything about $a$ or $f$ when the underlying category is cartesian closed, or any additional reasonable hypothesis?